# Unable to get response in json using twilio sdk

Tags: php, twilio

```
$sid = "XXXXXXXX"; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
$token = "XXXXXXXXX"; // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$message = $client->messages->create(
    $to_num,  //Text this number
    [
        'from' => '+1XXXXXXXXXXX', //From a valid Twilio number
        'body' => 'hello test message',
        "statusCallback" => "http://example.com/twilioSmsApi.php"
    ]
);
```

`[Twilio.Api.V2010.MessageInstance accountSid=ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX sid=SMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]`

I want response JSON format using Twilio PHP Library.

Comment: What is happening with the current code?

Answer (score 1):

You can access information of the response via individual object attributes, e.g.:

```php
$message->sid  // the sid
$message->body  // the body which was sent
$message->status  // the status of the message
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick response but how can i get the whole json response .Do you have any idea?

Comment: I personally am not aware of any SDK method to return the raw JSON of the API call. You can either reconstruct it by manually accessing all object attributes (see an [example JSON API response here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages?code-sample=code-send-an-sms-message&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x)) or you do the API call manually with [curl](https://www.php.net/curl).

Comment: @sauravsuman Since you can get all the attributes why do you need the whole JSON response?

Comment: As in every example on Twilio API doc ,they are showing JSON response  but i am not getting the JSON response , so I thought may be i did something wrong .That's why i wanted to get JSON response and asked here about Twilio SMS API,. Thanks